# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Aviation's [third moderator election](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: fooot]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking casey who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4779860738179072/0).

Answer (score 12):

Thanks everyone, looking forward to learning some new things and working with a great team!

Answer (score 10):

Welcome fooot. We are happy to have you here.

Now you've to quit other things in your life to concentrate on mod duties. They only take 22 hours each day. :)

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations! And welcome in the team! :)

Answer (score 7):

Welcome fooot. Glad to have you as part of the team.